# Port Forwarding Security Camera

Tags: networking, wireless-router, port-forwarding

I am having trouble port forwarding (opening ports) for my security cameras.

Network/Camera setup:

NETWORK:

- Arris router (ISP provided w/ coax going into it)
- Netgear smart (Personally bought , Arris connects to this which this then projects a 2.4ghz and a 5ghz wireless network, along with a 2.4ghz guest wireless connection.

CAMERA:

- One "Platnium" DVR - Configured network correctly
- One "Platnium" NVR - Configured network correctly

I need to know how to port forward these, as after opening the ports, an easy port scan shows that the ports are in fact closed.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do not do this unless you want to join the horde of unsecured or insecure Internet-accessible security cameras.

Answer (score 0):

I believe with Arris you would need to go to virtual server configuration.  Then you would need to put an inbound port (whatever port your camera system listens on).  Then the local port (same as camera system listens on) as well as an IP (internal IP of camera system).  Then browse to that IP (External) and see if you can hit it.  Once you can, there are plenty of port scanners online that will tell you if it's open and listening.  I usually use [MxToolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/portscan.aspx)

Comment: Hey, and thank you for your response! Sadly, I have already done all of this. it does not seem to solve my problem.. I do not understand, could it possibly be the fact that we have a "dual" setup, being a modem AND router? I wonder if we need to open ports on each.. If that is the case, then we will need to probably replace the Netgear.

Comment: Honestly, I always do a separate modem / router.  It's much easier to manage.  Your modem would just be your internet and your router would be where you open ports, etc.  It's much easier with separation for management.  What ports is it using?

Comment: What we are currently doing is using the Arris Modem provided by ISP to take in the coax. It has the DVR and NVR for the cams plugged directly into it, as well as a couple other things. We then have the Netgear "Smart" router plugged into the Arris. The Netgear does the wireless broadcasts and things of that nature. We need to open 80, 8000, 81, 8001 and two other that I don't know off the top of my head. We have them "opened" on the Arris and routed towards 192.168.0.102, which is the DVR (static) IP.

Comment: That should work perfectly (if they are directly plugged into the Arris).  It might be something your ISP is blocking on their end.  You  might have to reach out to them and see if they are blocking any ports and have them unblock those.  I know most ISPs block mail ports, but 80, 8000, 81 and 8001 are all fairly standard and I've never heard of them blocking those.  Does the DVR have a FW or anything that would need to be configured to allow traffic in?  Does it work internally but just not externally?

Comment: The ISP blocking could be it, although I doubt it seeing as it previously worked; worth a shot thought - calling them in a minute or two. The DVR does not seem to have a firewall, just a simple default gateway entry, ip entry, ports, etc. Nothing seems to be blocking it, because like I said, before we changed out all these routers and modems we did not have this issue.

Comment: So when you are on the network, it works fine?  Just externally it doesn't?  I'd be willing to bet it would be easily fixed with a new modem / router (not provided by your ISP)

Comment: No.. Say we are on our network, lets call it.. "Academy". I am on Academy and I want to see our cameras. I browse to 196.180.0.102, login, it works. Now I go to my house. Lets call the network "Tyler". I am on Tyler and get a text that our alarm system was disarmed, so I want to view our cameras to see who it is. I fire up "NVMS7000" app on my device. Before I view I have to type in: "Our Public Network IP:8000" and the login credentials, then I should be able to see the cameras, right? Wrong. It doesn't work. Before we changed out our gear, this worked fine.

Comment: Try a port scan and see if 8000 is open on that IP.  That will tell you quickly if your router is passing traffic through.  That's at least the place to start.  If not, and you have the rules in place, the ISP or replacing the modem / router is the next step!